# t3.medium and c5.18xlarge EBS initialization performance is same, or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: amazon-web-services

When booting up an application from an AMI we noticed increased response times and increased rate of request time-out errors, slowly tapering off and going back to normal. I figured this is due to EBS lazy initialization (a well-documented performance characteristic of EBS). The application has a 24 GB EBS data volume.

I tried increasing instance sizes and noticed no difference. So, taking a step back to try to isolate the performance bottleneck, I ran some benchmarks with different instance sizes to try to find the one with the best *pure EBS initialization performance*, under the assumption that this will serve as a good proxy for "performance with lazy initialization during normal use of the application".

**And I ran into a major surprise:**

A `t3.medium` instance performs the same as a `c5.18xlarge`!

How can this be?

I'm using the `fio` command recommended by AWS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html):

```
sudo fio --filename=/dev/nvme0n1 --rw=read --bs=128k --iodepth=32 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --name=volume-initialize
```

(modified for device /dev/nvme0n1)

the larger instance has nominally 5x the network performance of the smaller one (25 Gbps vs "Up to 5 Mbps").

Both plod along at about 35 MiB/s.

Bonus question: What instance type will give me the fastest EBS and S3 peformance, including, EBS initialization from snapshot?

**UPDATES**

1. Adding an S3 endpoint to the VPC made no difference.
2. When I increase the EBS volume size to the maximum 10,000 IOPS (i.e. 3333 GB), the speed goes up to
   about 45 MiB/s. I'm only testing on the c5.18xlarge at this point

Comment: What problem is this moderately slow restore speed causing you? Why do you need to restore from snapshots super fast? Perhaps we can help solve your problem in another way.

Comment: I updated the question to explain this

Comment: With more information we could help more. Are you trying to create an instance from an AMI because it has particular software installed, because it has a lot of data, both, or something else? I don't understand why you need super fast restores where the volume gets 100% of performance immediately. You could scale out and send traffic to the instance gradually to warm it, most of the traffic going to other instances until the new one is ready.

Comment: Getting 100% of performance immediately is not the goal, it is an indirect way to measure the performance penalty amortized during gradual warming, which is just as real but much harder to measure directly. "If you can't measure it, you can't improve it".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: **The initialization speed for EBS Snapshots is not affected by EC2 instance type.**

*As of 12/1/2018.*

Apparently 42 MiB/s is the maximum pre-warm / initialization rate that can be achieved from an EBS Snapshot to a single 10,000 IOPS volume. While the speed is not impacted by instance type, it does drop to 35 MiB/s on smaller volumes (100 IOPS). The speed is also not impacted by the presence of an S3 Endpoint on the VPC.

For comparison, copying directly from a live EBS volume to another, bypassing the snapshot process, performs at 128 MiB/s on an r5d.large instance, single-threaded, using a `tar|pv|tar` pipe, over an ext4 filesystem.

Comment: I wonder if volumes created from an AMI have this same limitation. You could try creating an AMI from the snapshot and creating a new instance from that, maybe it'll go faster. I suspect the AMI is stored in S3 and backed by a snapshot, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: They were AMIs already. I'll update

Comment: I suspect a multi-threaded copy would go significantly faster, up to the limits of the EBS / network connection of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

EBS snapshots are stored on S3 (this is documented on the link you provided above). When you restore a snapshot it pulls in blocks from S3 when they're required ([documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-restoring-volume.html), copied below).

> New volumes created from existing EBS snapshots load lazily in the
>   background. This means that after a volume is created from a snapshot,
>   there is no need to wait for all of the data to transfer from Amazon
>   S3 to your EBS volume before your attached instance can start
>   accessing the volume and all its data. If your instance accesses data
>   that hasn't yet been loaded, the volume immediately downloads the
>   requested data from Amazon S3, and continues loading the rest of the
>   data in the background.

**Updated Idea Again**

As Michael points out below, the bottleneck here is likely between S3 and EBS. I'm surprised it's so low at 35MB/sec aka 280Mbps, but I guess it's a single S3 object it's retrieving from. S3 can sustain huge bandwidth, but typically with multiple objects.

Based on what Michael says I think you just have to put up with this relatively slow restore. You don't have to pre-warm the volume, you can let it happen on demand and take the hit over the first minutes / hours / days the instance is up.

Comment: I'm using fio which is multi-threaded. The AWS account is a sandbox with default settings, default VPC, no NAT. There is no S3 endpoint, I would like to understand how it might help with EBS initialization? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Have a read of my edited answer. It's only a guess, someone else might have a better idea

Comment: @Tim you're on the right track -- there is a bottleneck, but the limitation is between the EBS *service* and S3 -- it is not between the instance (or anything inside the VPC) and S3.  You can only optimize this (e.g. with `fio`) up to the capability of EBS to restore the blocks, and essentially any modern instance class/size has enough EBS bandwidth to max-out what EBS provides for volume warm-up on demand.

Comment: Ah, good point @Michael-sqlbot. 35MB/sec (280Mbps) seems pretty slow between S3 and EBS.

Comment: It has been a while, but it seems like that is faster than I found the last time I tried benchmarking various warmup strategies.  My assumption is that EBS will only allow a finite amount of *something* (bits, blocks, etc.) to be allocated per volume for warmup.

Comment: I tried adding an S3 endpoint and it made no difference. Increasing the EBS volume size to 10,000 IOPS (3333 GB) helped some.

Comment: Based on what Michael said, I think AWS has a bottleneck in there somewhere deliberately. Why do you need to do this super fast? What happens to your application performance if you let it fetch blocks as required?

Comment: @Tim I expanded the question to describe the overall situation and use-case in a little more detail.